# Carregar Bitmap no PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, picturebox

Estou construindo um código para escanear biometrias. Como eu coloco a imagem gerada no dispositivo no pictureBox

O que uso para montar a imagem em bitmap

```
public Bitmap ExportarBitMap() // Exporta para o BitMap
{
            if (!Connected) // Valida se o dispositivo esta conectado
            {
                return null; // Retorna nulo se nao estiver
            }

            var t = new _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE(); // Armazena o tamanho em uma variavel coringa

            ftrScanGetImageSize(dispositivo, out t); // Recebe a imagem que vem do dispositivo

            byte[] arr = new byte[t.nImageSize]; // Retorna um array de bytes onde sao armazenados os tamanhos

            ftrScanGetImage(dispositivo, 4, arr); // Recebe o a imagem do scanner

            var bmp = new Bitmap(t.nWidth, t.nHeight); // Armazena na variavel coringa altura e largura da imagem

            for (int x = 0; x < t.nWidth; x++) // Percarro a largura da imagem
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < t.nHeight; y++) // Percorre a altura do dispositivo
                {
                    int a = 255 - arr[y * t.nWidth + x]; // inteiro recebe o array com a largura multiplicado pelo tamanho

                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, a, a)); // Monta a imagem
                }
            }

            return bmp; // Retorna a imagem montada
}
```

O que estou tentando fazer para adicionar ao pictureBox

```
using (Bitmap bmp = Leitor.ExportarBitMap())
{
    Image img; // Variavel do tipo Image
    img = (Image)(bmp); // Forca conversao atraves do cast

    pbBiometria.Image = img; // Insere a imagem no picture box
}
```

Comment: aparece algum erro?

Comment: Erro não aparece. Na imagem aparece um X vermelho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta de como montar a imagem

```
Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(bmp);
Graphics flagGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag);
int red = 0;
int white = 11;

while(white <=100)
{

   flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, red, 0, 0);

   flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, white, 0, 0);

   red += 20;
   white += 20;
}

pbBiometria.Image = flag;
```